# React Leaflet popup open after rerender

Tags: leaflet, maps, react-leaflet

I'd like to have my markers popup open even after rerender. I have a marker showing user position so that updates all the time. After that marker rerenders that closes the popup of other marker.

My code:

```
const StaticReferencePoints = (props) => {
  const { selectedCalibrationPoint, setSelectedCalibrationPoint, staticReferencePoints } = props;
  const addToast = useToastContext();
  const [snackbarOpen, setSnackbarOpen] = useState(true);
  const [latitude, longitude] = useGeolocationStoreHelper(['latitude', 'longitude']);
  const [map, setMap] = useState(null);

  const center = [latitude, longitude];
  const markerRef = useRef({});
  const [selectedMarker, setSelectedMarker] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    // open popup if it exists
    if (selectedMarker) {
      markerRef.current[selectedMarker]?.openPopup();
    }
  }, [selectedMarker, latitude, longitude]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (map) {
      map.addEventListener('click', () => {
        setSelectedMarker(null);
      });
    }
  }, [map]);

  const handleSnackbarClose = (event, reason) => {
    if (reason === 'clickaway') {
      return;
    }
    setSnackbarOpen(false);
  };

  const handleDeletePoint = (point) => {
    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this point?')) {
      Meteor.call(...) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          addToast('Error deleting point', 'error');
        }
        if (res) {
          console.log(res);
          addToast('Point deleted', 'success');
        }
      });
    }
  };

  const SingleMarker = (point) => {
    const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState(null);
    const handleClick = (event) => {
      setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
    };
    const handleClose = () => {
      setAnchorEl(null);
    };
    return (
      <Marker
        key={'staticPoint-' + point.point?.name}
        position={point.point?.coordinates}
        ref={(el) => (markerRef.current[point.point.name] = el)}
        eventHandlers={{
          click: () => {
            setSelectedMarker(point.point.name);
          },
        }}
      >
        <Popup options={{ autoClose: false }}>
          <Grid container item justifyContent={'center'} xs={12}>
            <Grid item container direction={'row'} xs={12}>
              <Grid item xs={1} container justifyContent={'center'} alignItems={'center'}>
                {ACL.check) && (
                  <div>
                    <IconButton size="small" onClick={handleClick}>
                      <MoreVertIcon />
                    </IconButton>
                    <Menu anchorEl={anchorEl} keepMounted open={Boolean(anchorEl)} onClose={handleClose}>
                      <MenuItem onClick={() => handleDeletePoint(point.point)}>
                        <ListItemIcon>
                          <DeleteIcon />
                        </ListItemIcon>
                        <ListItemText primary="Delete" />
                      </MenuItem>
                    </Menu>
                  </div>
                )}
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={10} container justifyContent={'center'} alignItems={'center'}>
                <Typography>{point.point?.name}</Typography>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={1}></Grid>
            </Grid>
            <Button
              onClick={() => {
                setSelectedCalibrationPoint(point.point);
                setSelectedMarker(null);
              }}
            >
              Select For Calibration
            </Button>
          </Grid>
        </Popup>
      </Marker>
    );
  };

  const StaticPointMarkers = () => {
    return staticReferencePoints.map((point, i) => {
      return <SingleMarker key={'marker-' + i} point={point} />;
    });
  };

  const UserPositionMarker = () => <Marker position={[latitude, longitude]} icon={userPosition}></Marker>;

  return (
    <Grid item xs={12}>
      <Snackbar
        anchorOrigin={{
          vertical: 'top',
          horizontal: 'center',
        }}
        open={snackbarOpen}
        onClose={handleSnackbarClose}
        autoHideDuration={5000}
        message="Calibrate first by selecting a point from the map"
        action={
          <IconButton size="small" aria-label="close" color="inherit" onClick={handleSnackbarClose}>
            <Close fontSize="small" />
          </IconButton>
        }
      />
      <MapContainer
        center={center}
        zoom={18}
        maxZoom={28}
        scrollWheelZoom={false}
        style={{ height: '65vh' }}
        whenCreated={setMap}
      >
        <TileLayer
          url="https://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}"
          maxZoom={28}
          subdomains={['mt0', 'mt1', 'mt2', 'mt3']}
        />
        {staticReferencePoints && <StaticPointMarkers />}
        {latitude && longitude && <UserPositionMarker />}
      </MapContainer>
      <Grid id={'info'} item container xs={12} justifyContent={'center'} marginTop={'1rem'}>
        <Typography>{`${latitude}, ${longitude}`}</Typography>
      </Grid>
      <Grid id={'info'} item container xs={12} justifyContent={'center'}>
        <InfoIcon onClick={() => setSnackbarOpen(true)} />
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
};

export default StaticReferencePoints;
```

I have now set current open popup on state and on useEffect open the popup but that creates flickering.

What would be the best way to force popup stay open?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you question, the problem is that the selected marker popup flickers when the user location changes?

In general the popup should be able to stay open as long as the marker is not created again.

I can see that you have `latitude` and `longitude` as dependencies in the useEffect they are not used in the useEffect tough. This will cause the useEffect too trigger on each update on `latitude` and `longitude`.
My first suggestion is to remove them from the dependency array.

Change this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    // open popup if it exists
    if (selectedMarker) {
      markerRef.current[selectedMarker]?.openPopup();
    }
  }, [selectedMarker, latitude, longitude]);
```

Secondly a good thing to do is to make sure that the popup is not already open this can be done with

To this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    // open popup if it exists
    if (selectedMarker && markerRef.current[selectedMarker]?isPopupOpen()) {
      markerRef.current[selectedMarker]?.openPopup();
    }
  }, [selectedMarker, markerRef]);
```

As a side note in my experience with react-leaflet, unnecessary rerenders can cause some visual irritation such as flickering. You should strive to reduce the amount of re renders. This can be done using `useMemo` and `useCallback` hooks. Genrally passing props that are functions, arrays or object might cause rerenders even if they are the same.

From what I can see your code is deeply nested and it looks like you define component inside other components. Try to break out you code to clear and clean components instead and pass props to them instead, you can still have them all in the same file.

Using a eslint and typescript might also help you to find issues with the code.

Answer (score 1):

Than you @Disco for your answer.

I managed to solve the problem with:

```
  const StaticPointMarkers = (markers) => {
return useMemo(() => markers.map((point, i) => <SingleMarker key={'marker-' + i} point={point} />), [markers])};
```